# Webpage won't stop redirecting to another page

Tags: php, redirect, dns, html

I used `window.location.replace` in my HTML file to test if the redirect works. Then I deleted the script function that redirected the web page but my HTML file won't stop redirecting.

So..I deleted the file completely, cleared my cache, cleared history, and everything and the web page still redirects to another page. The only thing that worked was that I changed my file name from `index.html` to `index.php`. However, even though `index.html` doesn't exist anymore after deleting and renaming it, it still redirects to another page when I enter in the URL

Anyone know how to fix this? I'm using domain.com btw.

EDIT: closed my browser and cleared my cache again and it for some reason worked. Not sure why it didn't work before that.

Comment: so it's redirecting and page is showing even after deleting? Is it?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Double check to make sure the file is deleted. Since you cleared your cache, that seems to be the only option. Unless you have a caching network such as a CDN between you and the web server or unless your host has your site in its own cache.